# How can I make calls related to a case display in its Chatter feed?

Tags: chatter-feed, cti, casefeed, log-a-call

I am using the Service Console in Lightning Experience, and using the Chatter Feed component on the Case layout to display updates to the Case.

If I use the "Log a Call" Quick Action from the Chatter publisher, these calls are displayed in the Chatter feed.  This is the desired behaviour.

However, if I insert a Log a Call record related to the Case any other way - e.g. using the Developer Console, or my CTI system's custom components - the call does not display in the feed.

If I query the record, it looks exactly the same as the record that is created with the Quick Action.  It just seems that the Chatter post is never made in this situation.

I have checked my Feed Tracking settings:

- Task has `Enable Feed Tracking` and `Subject` checked
- Case has `All Related Objects` checked

How can I enable calls created with a custom component (part of a CTI system) to display in the case feed?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the feed item is just "magic" that's executed by the publisher. As an example, if you run a `before insert` trigger on `Task` to change `TaskSubtype`, the published feed item will reflect the original subtype - i.e. it's not a normal sort of process run off the inserted sObject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in Apex if you fill out all the right fields.

```
Task t = new task(
    WhatId = someCase.Id, // Case to log against
    CallObject = 'Call Center To Log To', // Gotten from CallCenter object
    WhoId = someContact.Id,
    Subject = 'Outbound Call', // Can be whatever you want
    CallDurationInSeconds = 100,
    ActivityDate = Date.Today(),
    CallType = 'Outbound', // Inbound, Outbound, or Internal
    Description = 'Notes about the call here.',
    Status = 'Completed', // Make the call closed
    TaskSubType = 'Call', // To log a call
    Priority = 'High' // Any legal value okay here
);
insert t;
```

No need to insert a FeedItem, it'll work just like magic.

Despite what the documentation appears to say, this definitely works in my org. This also works in the REST API (and presumably others).

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a way to create a "Call logged" feed item on the Case, if you are not creating it from UI (or logged through CTI calls, details below).

Based on some quick tests below are my observations.

Whenever a call is logged from UI, a Task with *SubType* "Call" and *Status* "Completed" gets created. Additionally a [*FeedItem*](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm) is created with *Type* as *CallLogPost* and thus is visible in the Case Feed. And that based on this [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000176415&type=1), it seems that Feed Item records are created only from UI or a workflow:

> Call Logs are closed tasks and *you can only create the feed item that way via the "Create Call Log" button in the UI or via workflow updating the original call log task*. If you go and edit the task via standard UI edit, the feed sees the resulting record as a generic task, not a call log -- and you get the feed item formatted the way you experienced.

However, if you create a Task with same values, say from Developer Console, the *FeedItem* record that gets created is of type *CreateRecordEvent* (if you have feed tracking enabled), and that this *Type* is not applicable for Case Feed (refer to the documentation on *Type* in the *FeedItem's* documentation where a list of values are mentioned those are applicable for Case Feed).

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm) though mentions that a *FeedItem* with *Type* as *CallLogPost* does get created from CTI calls. So you should be able to see the feed item while logging CTI calls based on this.

> CallLogPost—generated event when a user logs a call for a case through the user interface. CTI calls also generate this event.

Unfortunately, you cannot create the *FeedItem* with *Type* field set to *CallLogPost* and that this field is not update-able.

---

So, in summary, any calls logged from UI or through CTI calls should be able to generate a "Call Logged" feed item on Case.

Comment: Thank you, Jayant.  I will follow up with the CTI vendor to investigate why their app isn't generating these feed posts (despite having enabled the option in their custom settings).

Comment: So, a bit late, but I actually found an answer.