# Is it possible to modify the Activity Timeline icons?

Tags: activity, log-a-call

In my org, when I create a new type of an activity: Log a call
[image]

It is shown like this in the activity time line:
[image]

- the icon looks like a task, but type is: Call
  [image]

I see in other orgs, that this icon looks more like a phone handset:
[image]

First question:

- How do I get this icon as well? what are the settings?

Second question:

- Is it possible to have other icons: such as: Linkedin, Whatsapp, Facebook ? or other icons, based on the activity type?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I get this icon as well? what are the settings?

The icon becomes a call icon when the Call fields are populated (CallObject, CallDuration, CallType), as described in an earlier [answer of mine](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/340664/2984). This also causes the Task to be logged as a Call in the Chatter Feed, if enabled for the object.

> Is it possible to have other icons: such as: Linkedin, Whatsapp, Facebook ? or other icons, based on the activity type?

No. There are fixed types based on the type of Activity and what fields are set. You cannot provide custom icons or select a specific icon for a given Activity.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the field that actually needs to be filled on the task is `SubType`.

I filled that field, but not `CallObject`, `CallDuration`, or `CallType`, and the icon changed to the blue call icon.